# Is there a way to let users edit something only if they are a members of an OG?

Tags: 7, organic-groups

We have a number of different users who want to edit 'sections' of our website. This mostly aligns to [Organic groups](https://www.drupal.org/project/og).

Is there a way to allow people to edit pages of a group which they are members of?

Comment: Have you visited this page: `admin/config/group/permissions`? There you can set permissions per group content and per group role respectively.

Comment: Yes, I see the group permissions. Is the solution to *not* allow in Drupal permissions but *do allow* in OG permissions. Is it that simple?

Comment: Why not? Have you tried it already? OG is a great module and has taken into consideration the group members and their actions. If that don't meet your needs, feel free to elaborate your thoughts.

Answer (score 1):

You could, for sure, use the [Group](https://www.drupal.org/project/group) module to let users edit something if they are a member of some ***group***. [Group](https://www.drupal.org/project/group) allows for creating arbitrary collections of your content and users on your site, and grant access control permissions on those collections. It is available as of D7, and has a D8 version also. It is designed to be an alternative to [Organic Groups](https://www.drupal.org/project/og). The [Group](https://www.drupal.org/project/group) module creates groups as entities, making them fully fieldable, extensible and exportable.

For this specific question, you'd enable the `gnode` submodule, and for each group type you would define the appropriate permissions (view, edit, delete, etc) for the various Content Types. That's it.

For more details about how [Group](https://www.drupal.org/project/group) compares to [Organic Groups](https://www.drupal.org/project/og), refer to my answer to "[What are the features of the Group module versus Organic Group module?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/197618/what-are-the-pros-and-cons-of-the-group-module-versus-organic-group-module/197622#197622)".

## Resources

- [Community documentation for the Group module](https://www.drupal.org/node/2666972).
- Video tutorial "[How to use the Group module in Drupal 8 to manage editorial access control to different areas of a web site](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=GkiCLJk5n0s)".

Comment: Upvote for making me aware of this module and a potential solution. However, this current site is knee deep in OG. I'm afraid of confounding the situation with OG and Groups. For the time being I'd like to stick to a purely OG based solution for this.

Comment: Hey @rgchi ... I can see your current objection (challenge?) for using the [Group](https://www.drupal.org/project/group) module. Would you be interested in another approach using the [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module ?